# Why do I get "s6-log: fatal: unable to open_append /run/service/app/lock: Not a directory"?

Tags: linux, alpine-linux, s6

I'm learning about [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/index.html) and I've come to a point where I want to use `s6-log`. I have the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:3.10

RUN apk --no-cache --update add s6

WORKDIR /run/service

COPY \
  ./rootfs/run \
  ./rootfs/app /run/service/

CMD ["s6-supervise", "."]
```

with `./rootfs/app` being just a simple `sh` script

```
#!/bin/sh

while true;
do
  sleep 1
  printf "Hello %s\n" "$(date)"
done
```

and `run` being

```
#!/bin/execlineb -P
fdmove -c 2 1
s6-log -b n20 s1000000 t /var/log/app/
/run/service/app
```

Why do I keep getting

> s6-log: fatal: unable to open_append /run/service/app/lock: Not a directory

? Without the `s6-log` line it all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that I've been doing this incorrectly. Namely I should've used `s6-svscan` instead of `s6-supervice`.
Using [`s6-svscan`](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-svscan.html) I can create a `log/` subdirectory in my service's directory so that my app's stdout is redirected to logger's stdin as described on `s6-svscan`'s website:

> For every new subdirectory dir it finds, the scanner spawns a s6-supervise process on it. If dir/log exists, it spawns a s6-supervise process on both dir and dir/log, and maintains a never-closing pipe from the service's stdout to the logger's stdin.

I've written `run` script like so:

```
#!/bin/execlineb -P
s6-log -b n20 s512 T /var/log/app
```

and with that I've changed the `CMD` to

```
CMD ["s6-svscan", "/run/"]
```

where `/run/service/` contains both `run` script for my service (without `s6-log` call) and `log` subdirectory with the `run` script above.